# How to be sure buildozer can build an .apk including KivyMD

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I want to develop an app in Python using Kivy and KivyMD.

In order to test Kivy, KivyMD and buildozer, I tried to export kitchen_sink (the included demo of KivyMD) as an apk. Buildozer did it, but the app crashes just after the loading screen.

Do you know what happened ? I would like to be sure a working app can be exported, as I don't want to waste time developing a program without knowing if I'll actually be able to create a functional app.

Thanks !

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Answer (score 1):

just add kivymd to requirement buildozer.spec

```
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
``requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,
```

also make sure that you add all extension file used (like iml, xml, txt ...)

```
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlasn,iml,xml,
```

Comment: I checked this and corrected what I needed, but the app still doesn't launch (crashed just after the loading screen with Kivy logo)

Comment: mybe it need # (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,

Comment: I deleted the # that started this specific line (#android.permissions = INTERNET), but the same thing happens...